# How to check if array contain null value and give default value swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array that's populated from a JSON response from an API server. Sometimes the values for a key in this array are Null

I am trying to take the given value and drop it into the detail text of a table cell for display.

The problem is that when I try to coerce the value into an String I get a crash, which I think is because I'm trying to coerce Null into a string.

What's the right way to do this?
ex-
my response is below type and I'm trying to fetch that array in self.imageArray variable

response = ["abc.jpg","null","xyzzy.jpg"]

```
 self.imageArray = (self.dataArray.value(forKey: "product_image") as? [String])!
```

but at second iteration it gets crashed coz second value is null.

Comment: Perform your iteration using `compactMap`. It can handle nil value. - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2950916-compactmap

Comment: Are the values in the array `null` or `"null"`?

Answer (score 1):

You can user `compatcMap` in this case.

```
 let response = ["abc.jpg", nil, "xyzzy.jpg"]
 let result = response.compactMap { $0 }
 print(result)
```

If you are sure the value will be "null" in string type then you can use the following way.

```
let response = ["abc.jpg", "null", "xyzzy.jpg"]
let result = response.filter { $0 != "null" }
print(result)
```

the combined result is

```
 let result = response.filter { $0 != "null" }.compactMap { $0 }
print(result)
```

Comment: how will you validate `"null"` this type string of null .. ?

Answer (score 1):

**In your case only** *(Solution according to given question 'response'
array) :-*

```
response = ["abc.jpg","null","xyzzy.jpg"]
```

**Use following code**

```
      if !response.contains("") && !response.contains("null"){
        //  No null or empty string now
        // your code
      }else{
           print("Contain null or empty value")
       }
```

Comment: how will you validate `"   "` empty string

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Bro ,first of all , this type of response are not good practice (my opinion) . If ur Back end developer can't manage this then you have to trim the all value of array string and then do like answer code . You can trim string like : let trimmedString = string.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) . This is actually what I will do in this scenario. It might be handle more optimize way .

Answer (score 1):

This will handle the issue for both null and nil.

```
response = ["abc.jpg","null","xyzzy.jpg", nil]
var result = response.filter { return ($0 != "null" && $0 != nil) }

print(result) // return option result.
```

Comment: That is iteration through the array twice. Not very good performance-wise. What if his array has 5000 items?

Comment: Now it is better, but as someone posted a comment in an another answer: what if there is an object like this: `" "`? :)

Comment: then you can add one more check the same as the other.

Comment: @ Shauket Sheikh- I get a crashes

Comment: Whats the response array?

Answer (score 0):

It should be like

```
var image = ["abc.jpg", nil, "xyzz.jpg"]
image = image.filter { $0 != nil}
print(image)
```

You have to filter out the nil values.

if you remove specific string "null"

```
var image = ["abc.jpg", "null", "xyzz.jpg"]
image = image.filter { $0 != "null"}
print(image)
```

Comment: how will you validate `"null"` this type string of null .. ?

Comment: Contact with your backend, it is their fault. `"null"` is a valid string.

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that a valid value will always contain an image type like `.jpg`, then you can check against that and it will remove `nil` values, `"null"` or any other random strings, including empty strings `" "`.

```
response = ["abc.jpg","null","xyzzy.jpg", nil, " "]
self.imageArray = response.filter { $0?.contains(".jpg") ?? false }
```

Comment: Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x10ea06e48) to 'NSString' (0x10d5554a8). I get this error

Comment: @ Starsky- I can't fetch array from response because of null value.it crashes

Comment: You can assign to your `self.imageArray` directly the filtered version of `response`. If it still has issues, then can you post a bigger portion of your code, where you handle your request response and you try to parse that JSON?